# "No component for supporting the service System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler was found" exception after upgrading RavenDb client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ravendb

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app that is using RavenDB client version 2.5.2879 and I want to upgrade that to version 3.0.30143. After I upgrade using NuGet the solution builds but when I run the app, this line throws an exception

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(xxxxCoreInstaller).Assembly, documentStore);
```

The exception that is thrown is

```
No component for supporting the service System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler was found
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal kernel, IReleasePolicy scope)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.Func`1Proxy.Invoke()
   at Raven.Client.Util.HttpClientCache.GetClient(TimeSpan timeout, OperationCredentials credentials, Func`1 handlerFactory) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Util\HttpClientCache.cs:line 110
   at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest..ctor(CreateHttpJsonRequestParams requestParams, HttpJsonRequestFactory factory) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Implementation\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 152
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequestFactory.CreateHttpJsonRequest(CreateHttpJsonRequestParams createHttpJsonRequestParams) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Implementation\HttpJsonRequestFactory.cs:line 86
   at Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<>c__DisplayClassde.<<GetIndexAsync>b__dd>d__e0.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Async\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 699
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.<TryOperationAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 443
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.<ExecuteWithReplicationAsync>d__19`1.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 338
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<ExecuteWithReplication>d__2d1`1.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Async\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Abstractions.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<<RunSync>b__8>d__d.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Util\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 75
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Raven.Abstractions.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Util\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 90
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.GetIndex(String name) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 223
   at Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask.Execute(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention documentConvention) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Indexes\AbstractIndexCreationTask.cs:line 293
   at Raven.Client.DocumentStoreBase.ExecuteIndex(AbstractIndexCreationTask indexCreationTask) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\DocumentStoreBase.cs:line 103
   at Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(ExportProvider catalogToGetnIndexingTasksFrom, IDocumentStore documentStore) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Indexes\IndexCreation.cs:line 155
   at Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(Assembly assemblyToScanForIndexingTasks, IDocumentStore documentStore) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Indexes\IndexCreation.cs:line 43
```

I have no idea why this happening and searching has produced nothing about this specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a very specific issue related to the interaction between RavenDB and Castle Windsor. I've asked a new question here:

[How do I use Castle Windsor to create a RavenDB session with client version > 3.0.3660?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054431/how-do-i-use-castle-windsor-to-create-a-ravendb-session-with-client-version-3)